# ACF Google Map - Marker Clustering

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I've been tearing my hair out (not that I have any...) trying to get my head round this, i'm using as close to the ACF Google Map example as I can, I have each location (post) plotting on the map fine but cannot for the life of me get clustering working properly, i'd really appreciate some help in the correct context of what i'm trying to do. None of the solutions i;ve found seem to resolve the issue.

```
InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama,

Uncaught TypeError: this.map_.getZoom is not a function
```

My JS is as follows (sorry for the post formatting!!!):

```
(function($) {

/*
*  render_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function render_map( $el ) {

    // var
    var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

    // vars
    var args = {
        zoom        : 16,
        center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    // create map               
    var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

    // add a markers reference
    map.markers = [];

    // add markers
    $markers.each(function(){
        add_marker( $(this), map );
    });

    // center map
    center_map( map );

    // add marker cluster
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer( map.markers, map );
}

// create info window outside of each - then tell that singular infowindow to swap content based on click
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content     : '' 
});


/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

    // var
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

    // create marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position    : latlng,
        map         : map
    });

    // add to array
    map.markers.push( marker );

    // if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
    if( $marker.html() )

    {

        // show info window when marker is clicked & close other markers
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            //swap content of that singular infowindow
            infowindow.setContent($marker.html());
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        // close info window when map is clicked
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
        if (infowindow) {
            infowindow.close(); }
        }); 
    }
}

/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

    // vars
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through all markers and create bounds
    $.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );
        bounds.extend( latlng );

    });

    // only 1 marker?
    if( map.markers.length == 1 )
    {
        // set center of map
        map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
        map.setZoom( 16 );
    }
    else
    {
        // fit to bounds
        map.fitBounds( bounds );
    }
}


/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.acf-map').each(function(){

        render_map( $(this) );
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

Any help would be awesome...

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. I fix it with include

```
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

In the footer and this is my code:

```
(function($) {

/*
*  new_map
*
*  This function will render a Google Map onto the selected jQuery element
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $el (jQuery element)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function new_map( $el ) {

// var
var $markers = $el.find('.marker');


// vars
var args = {
    zoom        : 16,
    center      : new google.maps.LatLng(46.8, 1.9),
    mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};


// create map               
var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);


// add a markers reference
map.markers = [];


// add markers
$markers.each(function(){

    add_marker( $(this), map );

});


// center map
center_map( map );

// add marker cluster
markerCluster( map.markers, map )

// return
return map;

}

/*
*  add_marker
*
*  This function will add a marker to the selected Google Map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*
*  @param   $marker (jQuery element)
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function add_marker( $marker, map ) {

// var
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( $marker.attr('data-lat'), $marker.attr('data-lng') );

// create marker
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position    : latlng,
    map         : map
});



// add to array
map.markers.push( marker );

// if marker contains HTML, add it to an infoWindow
if( $marker.html() )
{

    // create info window
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content     : $marker.html()
    });

    // show info window when marker is clicked
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

        if (typeof( window.infoopened ) != 'undefined') infoopened.close();
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        infoopened = infowindow;

    });
}


}

function markerCluster( markers, map ) {
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
    //console.log( markers );
}
/*
*  center_map
*
*  This function will center the map, showing all markers attached to this map
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   4.3.0
*  @param   map (Google Map object)
*  @return  n/a
*/

function center_map( map ) {

// vars
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// loop through all markers and create bounds
$.each( map.markers, function( i, marker ){

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng( marker.position.lat(), marker.position.lng() );

    bounds.extend( latlng );

});

// only 1 marker?
if( map.markers.length == 1 )
{
    // set center of map
    map.setCenter( bounds.getCenter() );
    map.setZoom( 16 );
}
else
{
    // fit to bounds
    map.fitBounds( bounds );
}

}


/*
*  document ready
*
*  This function will render each map when the document is ready (page has loaded)
*
*  @type    function
*  @date    8/11/2013
*  @since   5.0.0
*
*  @param   n/a
*  @return  n/a
*/
// global var
var map = null;

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.acf-map').each(function(){

    // create map
    map = new_map( $(this) );

});

});

})(jQuery);
```

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I added it as follows under `render_map()`. As suggested above you also need to add MarkerClustererPlus library in combination with the Maps JavaScript API to your scripts

```
// add marker cluster
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, map.markers, {
    imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'
});
```

Comment: The only thing I'd suggest differently here is to use the actual path to the clustering script provided in Step 2 of "Adding a Marker Clusterer" on this page: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/marker-clustering